# ROR Form_with keeps giving me a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm sure this should be a simple issue, but can't find a solution (im new to ROR).

This is the error im getting:

-----error------

NoMethodError in Agency::Clientmanagement#edit
Showing /home/ubuntu/environment/nacho/app/views/agency/clientmanagement/_form_client.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `client_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x007fcda8bd7ae0
Did you mean?  clients_path

<%= form_with model: @clientrecord do |f| %>

------ This is my routes------

```
root 'pages#home'
  get 'clients', to: 'clients#index'
  get 'agency', to: 'agency#index'
  get 'admin', to: 'admin#index'
  get 'clientview', to: 'agency#clientview'
  #post 'clientview', to: 'agency#clientview'
  
  namespace :admin do
    get "new", to: 'manager#new'
    get "add-user", to: 'manager#add-user'
    get "agencies", to: 'manager#agencies'
  end
  
  namespace :agency do
    resources :clientmanagement, only: [:show,:new, :create, :edit]
    resources :team, only: [:index, :show,:new, :create, :edit]
  end
```

-------this is the: admin/clientmanagementcontroller

```
class Agency::ClientmanagementController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_agencyaccount
  before_action :user_clients
  before_action :set_client, only: [:show]
  # before_action :set_one_product, only: [:show]

  # def index
  #   @all_shoe_products = @all_products.where(main_category_id: MainCategory.find_by_name("shoes").id)
  # end

  def show
  end
  
  def new
  end
  
  def create
  end
  
  def edit
     @clientrecord = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  
  def user_clients
    @clients = User.find(current_user.id).clients
  end
  
  def set_client
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end
```

--- here is the form_with in the form partial being rendered in /agency/clientmanagement/{id}/edit

```
<%= form_with model: @clientrecord do |f| %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please paste the `edit.html.erb` file. Also, try to find out if you used `client_path` instead of `clients_path`.

Comment: You indeed have not defined `client_path`, as noted by Hamid below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` file I don't see client_path is defined.

**Option 1**: You can add client path by adding the following route below clients path:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'clients', to: 'clients#index'
  get 'client',  to: 'clients#show'
  ...
end
```

this will generate the following path:

```
client_path   GET    /client(.:format)    clients#show
```

**Option 2**: If you have a full resource controller for `clients`, you can add

```
resources :clients
```

this will generate all RESTful routes for `clients`

```
     clients_path GET    /clients(.:format)          clients#index
                  POST   /clients(.:format)          clients#create
  new_client_path GET    /clients/new(.:format)      clients#new
 edit_client_path GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format) clients#edit
      client_path GET    /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#show
                  PATCH  /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#update
                  PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#update
                  DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#destroy
```

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is this is file is located in root/agency/clientmanagement/{id}/edit. This file is not located in the clients folder. Its in a subfolder of the agency folder.  In my routes i have the namespace for agency with resources for clientmanagement. I don't understsand why its trying to post to client_path. I don't see anywhere in the code where its calling to that.  Even though I haven't written the code for it yet,  once the client info is edited, the user will be redirected to root/agency/clientmanagement/{id}, So its never going through a clients path.

Comment: `<%= form_with model: @clientrecord do |f| %>`
generates 
`<form action="/client/:id" method="PATCH | POST" >`

the URL is client_path